# In Spark Json to Csv converting?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming, scala-collections

I have a Json object like bellow

```
{"Event":"xyz","Name":"test","Prog":0,"AId":"367","CId":"11522"}
```

using bellow spark script,I have converted into csv

```
 val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
 val df = sqlContext.load("org.apache.spark.sql.json", Map("path" -> "test1.json"))
 df.save("com.databricks.spark.csv", SaveMode.ErrorIfExists, Map("path" -> "datascv", "header" -> "true"))
```

I am able to convert  into CSV file,My Output is

```
AId,CId,Event,Name,Prog
367,11522,xyz,test,0
```

but here header of csv is in ascending  order,but I want to maintain my csv file header in customized format like bellow i.e same as my json order.

```
Event,Name,Prog,AId,CIdEvent,Name,Prog,AId,CId
```

Please help me with this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following.

```
val selectedData = df.select("Event", "Name", "Prog", "AId", "CId")
selectedData.save("com.databricks.spark.csv", SaveMode.ErrorIfExists,
                  Map("path" -> "datascv", "header" -> "true"))
```

Comment: This is working fine, but I want to know how can I get these key values dynamically  from Json,same as Json order.i.e In future if I have one more key extra.
for example now we have (Event,Name,Prog,AId,CIdEvent,Name,Prog,AId,Cid), In future if I have (Event,Name,Prog,AId,CIdEvent,Name,Prog,AId,Cid,yyy,zzz).
Please let me know how can I Handle dynamically,I dont want to touch my scala code .